# How to fix: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_nts_x64'?

Tags: php, dll, xampp, composer-php

I get this error while attempting to run a php command from cmd.exe on Windows 10 pro. Looking in the ext folder, I can see I have the dll.

[image]

I also have this line in my php.ini file:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I am using php version 8.0.13.

Here's some more info on the exact error:

[image]

I greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i commented this lines:

```
;extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64
;extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x86
;extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts_x64
;extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts_x86
;extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_nts
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts
```

I hope that my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).